# Being played $~$

Tags: riddle, word

Killing me right from the front,
the soil will turn over,
without you won't be able to live for long.

Stab me in the back,
I'm faster gone than you can run,
and yet you don't want to live without.

Rip my innards out,
all what's left is an old shiny antique
and yet you can't hold what you just removed.

Grabbing a pair from me,
you will either have something colorful
or something really old.

Hint 1

> Each stanza has one rule and two results.

Hint 2

> You can create 8 different words from the hints out of the parent word.

Hint 3

> There are no duplicated letters in the word and only a single vowel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Card

Killing me right from the front

> Take away the C -> Ard, an old plowing tool, without Vitamin C, you won't be living long

Stab me in the back

> Take away the D -> Car and another Vitamin

Rip my innards out

> What is left is a shiny old CD and AR (or Argon)

Grabbing a pair from me

> Gives you Cr (or Chromium - another shiny silvery metal) and AD (Anno Domini)

Answer (score 3):

Partial...Long shot. May not be correct answer but may be related to what OP mean by those lines..Might help someone.

Is the word -

> Heliosphere

Killing me right from the front,
the soil will turn over,
without you won't be able to live for long.

> HELIOSPHERE -> <s>HE</s> LIOSPHERE -> **LIOS** which is reversed SOIL

Stab me in the back,
I'm faster gone than you can run,
and yet you don't want to live without.

> HELIOSPHERE -> HELIOS<s>HERE</s> -> **HELIOS** is God of Light and light is fastest.

Rip my innards out,
all what's left is an old shiny antique
and yet you can't hold what you just removed.

> HELIOSPHERE -> H<s>ELIOSPHER</s>E -> **HE**. May be HE -> Helium -> Helium balloons are shiny. But its a stretch.

Grabbing a pair from me,
you will either have something colorful
or something really old.

> No idea...

Comment: You are on a good way, but this is not the correct word

Comment: @Zibelas- Yeah. I got the way. Hope someone hits the right word.

Comment: I suspect answer is something about elements. Oxygen seems related but not sure.

Comment: @shyos- I am not sure about that. But the word should follow the rules mentioned above.

Comment: I was under the impression each line was a separate word, not each stanza/paragraph, but okay

Comment: I never said it was not like that, you get one rule and two words per stanza (see second hint )

Answer (score 2):

Another partial, another long shot, and some *really tenuous* references... ;)
Also couldn't connect it to the title of the riddle.

Kudos to Techidot for some of the concepts they demonstrated.

Is the word:

> NEOLITHS

Killing me right from the front,
the soil will turn over,
without you won't be able to live for long.

> <s>N</s> EOLITHS (wouldn't live long without Nitrogen + anagram of THE SOIL)

Stab me in the back,
I'm faster gone than you can run,
and yet you don't want to live without.

> NEO <s>LITHS</s> (reference to the superfast Neo from the Matrix + liths, which is from an Old English word for 'limbs', which no-one wants to live without, I'd imagine)

Rip my innards out,
all what's left is an old shiny antique,
and yet you can't hold what you just removed.

> NEO <s>LI</s> THS (anagram of STHENO, one of the Gorgons, who Perseus defeated using a polished shield + Lithium, which you technically could hold, but probably wouldn't want to due to its corrosive nature)

Grabbing a pair from me,
you will either have something colorful
or something really old.

> <s>N</s> EOLITH <s>S</s> (eoliths were once thought to have been artifacts, the earliest stone tools + can't figure out the colorful reference...)

Comment: Great answer but still not the correct one, I added another hint.